# looping through row does not include last row

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that I found on web and modified to work for may application.  It loops through each row and executes the range value code until a blank row appears. It works great except it does not include the last row.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      Range("A2").Select
      For x = 2 To NumRows
         ' Insert your code here.
         If ActiveSheet.Range("T" & x).Value > 1 Then ActiveSheet.Range("G" & x).Value = "YES" ' Else
         If ActiveSheet.Range("T" & x).Value < 1 Then ActiveSheet.Range("G" & x).Value = "NO" ' Else
      '   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the NumRows variable will be 1 less than the last row number, because you start the count of rows in row 2. You can see that if you step through the code with F8 and inspect the variable.

You can fix that in various ways.

use `NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`

or use `NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1`

or use  `For x = 2 To NumRows + 1`